# How to allow control inside the splitview's pane close the pane in uwp?

Tags: c#, xaml, event-handling, uwp

I have a  customized control inside the splitview's pane. Now I have the method `hideinternal()` defined inside the control which makes the control invisible. However, at the same time I also want to close the pane. What should I do? (I know it is `SplitView.IsPaneOpen = false;` I don't know how to get access to it inside the control's code behind)

Answer (score 1):

I would raise an `event` from within `hideinternal` that can then be subscribed to in your view where you could hide the Pane.

eg in your Custom Control the event

```
public event EventHandler CloseSplitViewPane;

public void OnCloseSplitPaneView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CloseSplitViewPane?.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

in **hideinternal**

```
public void hideinternal()
{   
    OnCloseSplitViewPane(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

in your view for example MainPage.xaml.cs constructor (Your Custom Control is called MyControl in this example)

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    MyControl.CloseSplitViewPane += (sender, e) =>
    {
         SplitView.IsPaneOpen = false;
    };
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I ended up using another method, but any way thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I finally defined an event handler inside the control;

```
public event EventHandler handlesomething;
```

then in hideinternal I notify the event;

```
private void hideinternal()
{
    doSomething();
    this.NotifyEvent(handlesomething);
}
```

in the main page's XAML I sign the event handler to some events inside the page

```
<Control
   handlesomething ="SomeMethodsInsideMainPage"
/>
```